# WTI price in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-finance

Hi I'm trying to get the current WTI (West Texas Intermediate) price but GoogleFinance doesn't recognize it. Has anybody had luck with this?

Comment: Could you use importxml from cmegroup or some other site that post commodity prices and changes?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Found a solution. Google Sheets has an add-on and you can add the Yahoo Finance and then run formula =YAHOOFINANCE("ticker") and pick up commodities such as WTI (CL=F).

Answer (score 0):

With Yahoo, you can also get the information by decoding the json cntained in the web page. In A1 for instance `=marketPrice("CL=F")` and the script :

```
function marketPrice(code) {
  var url='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+code
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var jsonString = source.match(/(?<=root.App.main = ).*(?=}}}})/g) + '}}}}'
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonString)
  var regularMarketPrice = data.context.dispatcher.stores.StreamDataStore.quoteData.item(code).regularMarketPrice.raw
  return regularMarketPrice
}
Object.prototype.item=function(i){return this[i]};
```

Comment: So the script above works great in Apps Script and I can see the price in the Logs but on the Google Sheet there's nothing. I also notice there no assigned cell either so I would assume that is the reason for that. How would I make the code display on google sheets?

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("NYSE:WTI","price")
```

Comment: That's not it. It returned $3.49 and it's at $64.47 right now

Comment: Seems googlefinance is limited to what it shows

Comment: Use Yahoo instead

Comment: So above I said I use the add-on YAHOOFINANCE but the problem I'm running into now is that after about an hour I get an error message in the cell where the price is suppose to be shown.